# Как получить район города?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api

Задача проста: вывести район по точному адресу или координатам объекта недвижимости.
Собственно, вот что гугл выводит: 
[ссылка](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0,%20%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%2038,%20%D0%A2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD,%20%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3)
В запросе обратного геокодирования пробовал указать:

```
types: ["political","sublocality_level_1","sublocality_level_2","sublocality_level_3","sublocality"] ...
```

не помогает.
В [документации](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=ru) написано что есть такой необязательный параметр "bounds", содержащий ограничивающий прямоугольник, в который полностью помещается возвращенный результат.
Только вот как же его получить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

при получении ответа от гугл, извлечь results["address_components"][3]["long_name"] !

Comment: @Максим147 прошу прощения за столь долгий отклик. Я не совсем вас понял, я отправляю запрос: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0,%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0&sensor=false&language=ru там нет этого параметра...